# Which are the value folder names and layout folder names in android

Tags: android

Which are the value folder names and layout folder names that I can used to support multiple screen sizes and dpi values. Looking for the complete list of devices with 4.1+
Thank you

Comment: [Have you checked the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
-For layouts you can specify 
    res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
    res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
    res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
    res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
    res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
-- If you want to specify the screen basing on the dp you can spicify the name as

```
res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

-- If you want to specify basing on the smallest width you can specify as

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)

[for more detail click here][2]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but i'm looking the complete list of the layouts. for example
res/layout
res/layout-sw600dp
res/layout-sw720dp
res/layout-small
res/layout-large

Comment: for more detail check this link  http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

Under your project, you will find a folder called "res". You need to supply different images to different screen sizes inside the drawable folders.
For example, inside the folder drawable-hdpi you will add your hdpi images, inside the folder drawable-mdpi you will add your mdpi images and so on...
Also, if you have a missing folder, for example for the xxhdpi dpi, you can just create the folder under the res folder (drawable-xxhdpi) and add your xxhdpi images.